# Постинг в группу вконтакте на Python

Tags: python, вконтакте

Искал везде, так и не могу сделать, чтобы код публиковал в группу пост. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать метод [wall.post](https://dev.vk.com/method/wall.post)